# How to create custom high-def images in Java

Tags: java, bufferedimage, graphics2d

I am creating images in Java that have fonts written on them with a transparent background. I make the fonts different colors and also different types of font styles so I need the program to be dynamic. The issue is that I am using Graphics2D and writing on a Buffered Image using g2d.drawString() and the images aren't nearly the definition I'm looking for. I've tried creating large images with large font sizes and then downscaling but that doesn't work either. I also have set all of the possible RenderingHints to highest definition. I would like the pixel density to be high enough that there isn't much of a difference if you compared it with regular text on a retina screen. Thanks.

Comment: From what I understand, Retina resolution is achieved by downsizing an image by around 4 times. So, you need to decide on your target resolution and scale the image up by 4 times, render your output and downscale it by 4...I think...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To have "retina" quality images in Java, you must create and render your `BufferedImage` at 2 times the normal size in both dimensions (this will make the image 4 times as large, which I think is what @MadProgrammer means).

Then, you must *not* downsample (or "scale") the image in Java, but instead keep the `BufferedImage` in full size, and only draw the image in half size to a native backed `Graphics2D` instance. The  `Graphics` object passed to the `paint()` or `paintComponent()` methods of an AWT or Swing component is normally fine (while the one from `BufferedImage.get/createGraphics()` isn't).

I've used code like this with success:

```
@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    AffineTransform xform = AffineTransform.getScaleInstance(.5, .5);
    g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION,
                        RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BILINEAR);
    g2.drawImage(image, xform, null); // image being @2x or "retina" size
}
```

However, note that the font rendering on modern computer uses ["sub pixel antialiasing" or "sub pixel rendering"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subpixel_rendering), which is specific to the screen device you are rendering to (see the link, but basically, the RGB pattern or "layout" differs from device to device). This means a `BufferedImage` usually can't use sub pixel rendering, and thus fonts will look less crisp. If you are rendering to a single LCD screen, you might be able to specify one of the  [`RenderingHints.TEXT_ANTIALIAS_LCD_*`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/text/renderinghints.html) rendering hints for better results.

Comment: when you say that getting the graphics object from .createGraphics() isn't good, how am I getting the "g" variable you described?

Comment: I am eventually exporting this image as a PNG and using it else where.

Comment: @user3168190 As I said, you get the `Graphics` passed into the `paint()` method of your Swing (or AWT) application. However, depending on where "elsewhere" is, this might not apply. Just write the PNG in full @2x size (double in both dimensions). Then, control the rendering as appropriate, ie. if "elsewhere" is on the web, use CSS to render at half size.

Comment: I'd love to see the sample code expanded. Show how to create the `Graphics2D` object, maybe even show how that can be written to a file again.

Comment: @MartinKlepsch As I say in the answer, you must use the `Graphics` object passed to the `paint()` or `paintComponent()` method for this to *display* correctly. I can add that code. But if you simply want to write an image to disk at 2x size, just do it. There's no magic needed. :-)